# QR CODE not showing when printing JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, printing

I have a Qr code which i want to print. Qr code is showing fine in the page but when i try to print it it's not showing.

in home page - [image]

in print page -

[image]

Html

```
<div class="container" id="printarea">
        <div class="card"style="height: 386px;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <center>
             <div id="qrcode"></div>
             <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
            Powered by <img src="{{env('APP_URL')}}/public/{{$app_setting->webLogo}}" class="logo-icon" alt="logo icon" style="width:40px;">
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

JQuery Qr Code

```
<script>
 var qrcode1 = "{{Auth::guard('vendor')->user()->VendorURL}}";
 jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#qrcode').qrcode(qrcode1);
 })
</script>
```

Qr code printing code

```
function printFunc() {
var divToPrint = document.getElementById('printarea');
var htmlToPrint = '' +
    '<style type="text/css">' +
    'table th, table td {' +
    'border:1px solid #000;' +
    'padding;0.5em;' +
    '}' +
    '</style>';
htmlToPrint += divToPrint.innerHTML;
newWin = window.open("");
newWin.document.write("<h3 align='center'>QR Code</h3>");
newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
newWin.print();
newWin.close();
```

Comment: So what does this random library do to produce a QR Code? My guess it is background color and not an image. And your set up to not print background colors....

Comment: it's a Qr code generated by jquery given below

Comment: And what does the library you found produce to generate the QR code? Looks like you need to find one that generates and image and not HTML with background colors.

Comment: this code is not written by me but has to solve this bug

Comment: I know.... I was asking for you to figure out what it generated. Actually inspect the output and see what the library created for the QR code.  You solution to the problem is... find a different library.

Answer (score 1):

I have get this Solution - Converting the QR Code to an Image

```
var canvas = $('#qrcode canvas');
var img = canvas.get(0).toDataURL("image/png");
newWin = window.open("");
var ig = '<p style="text-align: center;">Powered by <img src="{{env('APP_URL')}}/public/{{$app_setting->webLogo}}" class="logo-icon" alt="logo icon" style="width:40px;"></p>';
newWin.document.write("<h3 align='center'>QR Code</h3>");
newWin.document.write('<img style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" src="'+img+'"/>');
newWin.document.write(ig);
setTimeout(function() {
newWin.print();
newWin.close();
}, 250);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Enable Background Graphics from print preview page,
Click on more settings you can see it